# C# collection of two points doesn't return any results

Tags: c#, linq, iequalitycomparer

Class:

```
public class Point : IEqualityComparer<Point>
{               
    public char HorizontalPosition { get; set; }
    public int VerticalPosition { get; set; }

    public Point(char horizontalPosition, int verticalPosition)
    {
        HorizontalPosition = char.ToUpper(horizontalPosition);
        VerticalPosition = verticalPosition;           
    }   

    public bool Equals(Point x, Point y)
    {
        return (x.VerticalPosition == y.VerticalPosition && x.HorizontalPosition == y.HorizontalPosition);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Point obj)
    {
        return (obj.HorizontalPosition.GetHashCode() + obj.VerticalPosition.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

I am trying to find common Points (intersection) in two collections, but the result is empty collection - two elements should be in it. Why? I've implemented IEqualityComparer. Did I did something wrong?

Example collections:

```
  List<Point> first = new List<Point> { new Point('a', 1), new Point('b', 2) };
  List<Point> second = new List<Point> { new Point('a', 1), new Point('b', 2) };
  List<Point> intersection = first.Intersect(second).ToList();
```

Intersection is empty list, but two elements should be in it.

Comment: Wow, the documentation looks wrong. Your type should implement `IEquatable<Point>`, not `IEqualityComparer<Point>`

Comment: @Dennis_E Except that it won't work as you expect. Here's why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645891/why-isnt-except-linq-comparing-things-properly-using-iequatable

Comment: @decPL That link talks about it not working if you don't implement `GetHashCode()`. But he has, so I don't see why it won't work as expected.

Comment: That links talks about it not working if you don't **override** `public int GetHashCode()`. What he did is he provided an implementation for `IComparable<T>.GetHashCode(T)` which will never get called for reasons others specified in their answers. And if you don't trust me - check for yourself.

Comment: @decPL I didn't notice it was `IEqualityComparer<Point>.GetHashCode()` and not `object.GetHashCode()`. Anyway, that's going into detail of actually implementing `IEquatable<T>`. I was only making a remark on the documentation saying `IEqualityComparer<T>` instead of `IEquatable<T>`. The sentence looks wrong: "The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of the types that implement the IEqualityComparer<T> generic interface."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Point> first = new List<Point> { new Point('a', 1), new Point('b', 2) };
            List<Point> second = new List<Point> { new Point('a', 1), new Point('b', 2) };
            List<Point> intersection = first.Intersect(second, new PointComparer()).ToList();


public class Point 
{
    public char HorizontalPosition { get; set; }
    public int VerticalPosition { get; set; }

    public Point(char horizontalPosition, int verticalPosition)
    {
        HorizontalPosition = char.ToUpper(horizontalPosition);
        VerticalPosition = verticalPosition;
    }
}

public class PointComparer : IEqualityComparer<Point>
{
    public bool Equals(Point x, Point y)
    {
        return (x.VerticalPosition == y.VerticalPosition && x.HorizontalPosition == y.HorizontalPosition);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Point obj)
    {
        return (obj.HorizontalPosition.GetHashCode() + obj.VerticalPosition.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Try above example

Answer (score 5):

`IEqualityComparer` is an interface you can give to the `Intersect` method to compare items. It is not used by default to compare anything. So your code is just using the built-in `Equals` in `Object` which will return false unless the objects are the same object.

You have to either override the default `Equal` and `GetHashCode` methods in the class or tell the intersection to use your implementation of the comparer. But you shouldn't implement the comparer in a data storage class.

Answer (score 5):

You should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` from object:

```
public class Point
{
    public char HorizontalPosition { get; set; }
    public int VerticalPosition { get; set; }

    public Point(char horizontalPosition, int verticalPosition)
    {
        HorizontalPosition = char.ToUpper(horizontalPosition);
        VerticalPosition = verticalPosition;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        { 
            return (HorizontalPosition * 397) ^ VerticalPosition;
        }
    }

    protected bool Equals(Point other)
    {
        return Equals(HorizontalPosition, other.HorizontalPosition) && Equals(VerticalPosition, other.VerticalPosition);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Point)obj);
    }
}
```

You could also implement a custom `IEqualityComparer` and pass it to `intersect`:

```
public class PointComparer : IEqualityComparer<Point>
{
    public bool Equals(Point a, Point b)
    {
        return a.HorizontalPosition == b.HorizontalPosition && a.VerticalPosition == b.VerticalPosition;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Point p)
    {
        unchecked
        { 
            return (p.HorizontalPosition * 397) ^ p.VerticalPosition;
        }
    }
}

// ...

List<Point> intersection = first.Intersect(second, new PointComparer()).ToList();
```

As mentioned in the comments by @decPL, you should also reconsider your hash code implementation.

Comment: One additional point - OP's GetHashCode implementation is not perfect, as it will create a lot of collisions (hash code for (x,y) == hashcode for (y,x) for any x and y). It's better to use something like `unchecked { return (this.HorizontalPosition * 397) ^ this.VerticalPosition; }`

Comment: Thanks @decPL! That is true and should be implemented that way. I update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unless specified, `Intersect` uses `EqualityComparer<Point>.Default` which will use the `object.Equals` and `object.GetHashCode` methods for comparison (they will just check if the reference is the same);

to make it work, pass the comparer to the method:

```
  List<Point> first = new List<Point> { new Point('a', 1), new Point('b', 2) };
  List<Point> second = new List<Point> { new Point('a', 1), new Point('b', 2) };
  List<Point> intersection = first.Intersect(second, new Point('a', 0)).ToList();
```

Although, ideally for the **SRP** you shouldn't have the comparer on the `Point` class itself as it would look hacky as it looks above creating a `Point` just as logic class for comparison.

**From MSDN:**

[EqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should separate your Point and PointComparer classes.

The manual has good example:

```cs
public class ProductA
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
}

public class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<ProductA>
{

    public bool Equals(ProductA x, ProductA y)
    {
        //Check whether the objects are the same object. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal. 
        return x != null && y != null && x.Code.Equals(y.Code) && x.Name.Equals(y.Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ProductA obj)
    {
        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
        int hashProductName = obj.Name == null ? 0 : obj.Name.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the Code field. 
        int hashProductCode = obj.Code.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the product. 
        return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As you can find on reference https://referencesource.microsoft.com/

**System\Linq\Enumerable.cs**

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second) {
                if (first == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
                if (second == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
                return IntersectIterator<TSource>(first, second, null);
            }

...
    static IEnumerable<TSource> IntersectIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
        {
            Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
            foreach (TSource element in second) set.Add(element);
            foreach (TSource element in first)
                if (set.Remove(element)) yield return element;
        }
...
// If value is in set, remove it and return true; otherwise return false
        public bool Remove(TElement value) {
            int hashCode = InternalGetHashCode(value);
            int bucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;
            int last = -1;
            for (int i = buckets[bucket] - 1; i >= 0; last = i, i = slots[i].next) {
                if (slots[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(slots[i].value, value)) {
                    if (last < 0) {
                        buckets[bucket] = slots[i].next + 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        slots[last].next = slots[i].next;
                    }
                    slots[i].hashCode = -1;
                    slots[i].value = default(TElement);
                    slots[i].next = freeList;
                    freeList = i;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Your comparer actually doesn't used