# c# Remove items in a custom list, based on another List<int>

Tags: c#, list

I have a custom list List. which returns all items. The structure of Info is as follows:

```
public class Info
  {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string ClinicianDescription { get; set; }
  }
```

I want to exclude any Info objects from the list where the Code property equels any value in a separate List.

Just after a clean way to do this, i've tried using .Except(), but i would have to convert the List into the same object which seems incorrect.

I've tried something like this so far:

```
List<int> ids = contactList;
var List<Info> test = info.RemoveAll(x => ids.Any(i => i == x.Code));
```

Comment: Why don't you use a loop? Are you looking for a clean way or a *hard way*?

Comment: `var List<Info> test` ... would result in compilation error though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `Except`, although this takes an `IEnumerable`, not a predicate, and you need to be careful when using this with custom classes when determining the [equivalence of two objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1646041/314291)

```
var blackListCodes = contactList.Select(i => i.ToString()); 
var test = info.Except(info.Where(i => blackListCodes.Contains(i.Code)));
```

But as Tomassino has pointed out, this can be inverted and simplified as:

```
var test = info.Where(i => !blackListCodes.Contains(i.Code))
```

Note that this will project a *new* Enumerable, rather than change elements in the existing `info`, which `RemoveAll` does.

Just some other points - re your code sample:

- As others have pointed out, the type used in the `Code` match needs to be compatable in the comparison, i.e. you can't compare `string Code` with the ints in `ids`. Here, because we're using `.Except` on the same source collection, comparison of elements will work as expected, even if it relies on default reference equality (since it's the same element reference in both `IEnumerables`).
- [`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an int representing the number of elements pruned from the list - the result can't be assigned to another `List`.

Comment: This will not work because `i` is an `int`. Need to parse one or call ToString() on the other.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this approach:

```
 List<Info> info = new List<Info>();
 //fill info with objects

 List<string> excludeCodes = new List<string>();
 //fill excludeCodes with values

 var result = info.Where(i => !excludeCodes.Contains(i.Code)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use `Contains()` like

```
List<Info> test = info
                     .Where(i => !ids.Contains(i.Code)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you try to compare string with int!