# How to manage this situation by generic programming in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the code below which implements a logic I need at two places in my code. The code is written in generic way.

It has a defect in it. It does not check whether the given object already exist in the collectionToBeExtended or not. It just add to it, and I will have twice the same item.

I use this code managing two collections, one contains Tags, the other one contains Link entities (POCO). They do not have the same parent object, nor interface. For managing the situation below I don't want to introduce a new common interface for them.

In order to fix the defect above I need put custom logic within the foreach to check whether the given object already member of the collection or not. The Tag and Entity object are different, so there is common ground for comparison. You can see the Tag implementation below.

DRY principle says clearly I should not create the exact implementations, instead I should create some generic solution can deal with both case, or a third and fourth one. My first thought was that, I introduce a switch where I can place custom logic based on object type, but Martin Fowler says in his Refactoring book that switch-cases are smelly areas.

My current knowledge and experience is not enough to solve this issue, so I really appreciate any help!

**Generic implementation**:

```cs
private ICollection<T> AddTo<T> ( IEnumerable<T> toBeAdded , ICollection<T> collectionToBeExtended )
    {

        if ( collectionToBeExtended == null )
        {
            collectionToBeExtended = new List<T> ( );
        }

        if ( toBeAdded != null )
        {
            foreach ( T obj in toBeAdded )
            {
                    collectionToBeExtended.Add(obj);
            }
        }

        return collectionToBeExtended;
    }
```

**Tag implementation**:

```cs
private ICollection<Tag> AddTo ( IEnumerable<Tag> toBeAdded , ICollection<Tag> collectionToBeExtended )
    {

        if ( collectionToBeExtended == null )
        {
            collectionToBeExtended = new List<Tag> ( );
        }

        if ( toBeAdded != null )
        {
            foreach ( Tag tag in toBeAdded )
            {
                if (!collectionToBeExtended.Any(c => c.Id == tag.Id && c.Name == tag.Name))
                {
                    collectionToBeExtended.Add(tag);
                }
            }
        }

        return collectionToBeExtended;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All types in C# can equated with `x.Equals(y)`. You can override this equality if you desire.

I would just use `IEnumerable<A>` to solve this problem. If you want an `ICollection<A>` afterwards then you can construct a collection from the `IEnumerable<A>`.

```
collectionToBeExtended.Concat(toBeAdded).Distinct()
```

- [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: +1 I think this is best. Note that the result will also remove any duplicates in the original `collectionToBeExtended`, which may or may not be expected. (Seems to be implied by the question.)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this isn't overkill, but extension methods seem to do the trick for me. I hope it helps you too.

```
public static ICollection<X> AddIf<X>(this ICollection<X> myarray, X val, Func<X, X, bool> check)
    {
        if (myarray.All<X>((c) => check(c, val))) myarray.Add(val);
        return myarray;
    }
```

This can then be used as

```
List<string> test = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
test.AddIf<string>("1", (a, b) => !a.Equals(b)); //this will not be added
test.AddIf<string>("6", (a, b) => !a.Equals(b)); //this will be added
```

Or in your case,

```
collectionToBeExtended.AddIf((c, tag) => !c.Id.Equals(tag.Id) && !c.Name.Equals(tag.Name))
```

Make sure to put the extension method in a static class though.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `IEquatable<T>` for `Tag`

```
public class Tag : IEquatable<Tag>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Equals(Tag other)
    {
        return Id == other.Id && Name == other.Name;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then your codes would be

```
private ICollection<T> AddTo ( IEnumerable<T> toBeAdded , ICollection<T> collectionToBeExtended )
{

    if ( collectionToBeExtended == null )
    {
        collectionToBeExtended = new List<T> ( );
    }

    if ( toBeAdded != null )
    {
        foreach ( T t in toBeAdded )
        {
            if (!collectionToBeExtended.Contains(t))
            {
                collectionToBeExtended.Add(t);
            }
        }
    }

    return collectionToBeExtended;
}
```

You have to implement `IEquatable<T>` for all the classes you want to pass them to the `AddTo` method. And remember to implement it correctly. See [Is there a complete IEquatable implementation reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307493/is-there-a-complete-iequatable-implementation-reference).

There is another option. Just add another parameter to compare the two entities, like

```
private ICollection<T> AddTo<T>(IEnumerable<T> toBeAdded, ICollection<T> collectionToBeExtended, Func<T, T, bool> comparer)
{

    if (collectionToBeExtended == null)
    {
        collectionToBeExtended = new List<T>();
    }

    if (toBeAdded != null)
    {
        foreach (T t in toBeAdded)
        {
            if (!collectionToBeExtended.Any(existingT => comparer(t, existingT))))
            {
                collectionToBeExtended.Add(t);
            }
        }
    }

    return collectionToBeExtended;
}
```

Then you call this method like `AddTo(tags, collection, (t1, t2) => t1.Id == t2.Id && t1.Name == t2.Name);`. If either of the collection has large data, the performance should be considered.

Answer (score 1):

If you implemented `IEquatable<T>` in `Tag` and any other classes you use with this method, and add a generic constraint `where T:IEquatable<T>` to your method you can now scan the collection for existing members and compare them for equality.

But you'd simply be duplicating code that already exists in `HashSet<T>` so why not use that class with the constructor `HashSet<T> Constructor (IEqualityComparer<T>)`?

Comment: It is valid using such a solution on Entity Framework entities?

Comment: Yes, you can add `IEquatable<T>` to EF entity classes (partial or POCO).